# Div won't resize vertically to fit the text. No position:relative or anything like that

Tags: html, resize

My main body div won't resize to fit my text.

My setup is a main body container div. In that div there is the header div, the body div and the footer div. In the body div there are 3 divs called body-left, body-middle and body-right. These are all side by side using the css style float:left

I have tried setting the height of the bodycontainer, the min-height of bodycontainer, and the same for the divs in bodycontainer.

here is a screenshot of whats happening: https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0ohT.jpg

Here is my html:

```
<div id="maincontainer">
<div id="headercontainer">
    <a href="/index.html"><div id="header-logo"></div></a>
    <div id="header-navbar">
        <div id="navbar" align="center">
            <a href=""><div>Home</div></a>
            <a href=""><div>Roster</div></a>
            <a href=""><div>FAQ</div></a>
            <a href=""><div>Donate</div></a>
            <a href=""><div>About</div></a>
            <a href=""><div>Contact</div></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="bodycontainer">
    <div id="body-left">
        <ul>
            <div>
                <a href="http://www.facebook.com/darkonyxftw" title="Click to go to our Facebook page." target="_blank">
                                    <div class="social-odd">
                                    <h3 class="social">Facebook</h3>
                                    <p class="social">All tweets and youtube uploads, as well as updates and notifications go on our facebook. Like our page to get the notifications on your wall.
                                </p>
                                <p class="social">facebook.com/DarkOnyxFTW</p>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                        <a href="http://www.youtube.com/subscription_center?add_user=darkonyxftw" title="Click to subscribe to our Youtube channel." target="_blank">
                                    <div class="social-even">
                                    <h3 class="social">Youtube</h3>
                                    <p class="social">Entire practice sessions, special event videos, VODS and casts get uploaded to our youtube channel. click here to subscribe.
                                </p>
                                <p class="social">youtube.com/DarkOnyxFTW</p>
                            </div>
                      </a>
                      <a href="http://www.twitter.com/DarkOnyxFTW" title="Click to go to our twitter page." target="_blank">
                                    <div class="social-odd">
                                    <h3 class="social">Twitter</h3>
                                    <p class="social">Everytime we upload a youtube video or our stream goes online on twitch.tv/DarkOnyxFTW, you will know about it if you follow our twitter account.
                                </p>
                                <p class="social">twitter.com/DarkOnyxFTW</p>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                        <a href="http://www.twitch.tv/DarkOnyxFTW" title="Click to go to our twitch.tv channel." target="_blank">
                                    <div class="social-even">
                                    <h3 class="social">Live Stream<br>@ Twitch.tv</h3>
                                    <p class="social">We live stream our practices every Monday, Wednesday and Thursday at 7PM PST (9PM Central). Follow our twitch channel to get an email notification when we go live. We will also be streaming clan battles and other special events, so keep an eye on your inbox for that.
                                </p>
                                <p class="social">twitch.tv/DarkOnyxFTW</p>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                        <a href="http://www.teamliquid.net/blog/DarkOnyx" title="Our TeamLiquid Blog" target="_blank">
                                    <div class="social-odd">
                                    <h3 class="social">Team Liquid Blog</h3>
                                    <p class="social">Click here for player interviews, clan war information and much more.
                                </p>
                                <p class="social">teamliquid.net/blog/DarkOnyx</p>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="body-middle">

    </div>
    <div id="body-right">

    </div>
</div>
<div id="footercontainer">
    <div style="width:590px; padding-left:10px; padding-top:10px;">Site by Alex "Xzar" Mohr</div>
    <div id="footer-nav" style="" align="right">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/about/about.html">About</a></li> | 
            <li><a href="/contact/contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

here is my css: http://darkonyx.webatu.com/style2.css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#bodycontainer{
    width:100%;
    height:1000px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
}
```

This limits the height to 1000px, which is less than the length of the text.

Comment: if i get rid of that, it doesn't show the background of the body at all, but the text stays there. if i change that to min-height it still won't go higher

Comment: What if you remove the height limitation from `#bodycontainer`, and also remove `height:100px` from `#body-left` and remove `float:left` from `#body-left`?

Comment: if I remove the float:left, won't make them not beside each other?